# Parsing JSON to an object

Tags: ios, json

I'm trying to parse this JSON:

```
{
    "GetMachineGroupsResult": {
        "MachineGroups": [
            {
                "GroupCount": 1,
                "GroupID": 101,
                "GroupName": "Machine11"
            },
            {
                "GroupCount": 6,
                "GroupID": 201,
                "GroupName": "Machine12"
            },
            {
                "GroupCount": 1,
                "GroupID": 301,
                "GroupName": "Machine13"
            },
            {
                "GroupCount": 1,
                "GroupID": 501,
                "GroupName": "Machine14"
            },
            {
                "GroupCount": 7,
                "GroupID": 701,
                "GroupName": "Machine15"
            },
            {
                "GroupCount": 1,
                "GroupID": 901,
                "GroupName": "Machine16"
            },
            {
                "GroupCount": 1,
                "GroupID": 1001,
                "GroupName": "Machine17"
            }
        ],
        "Status": 0
    }
}
```

Into an object created with attributes GroupCount, GroupID and GroupName.

Here is my code:

```
if (request.responseStatusCode >= 200 && request.responseStatusCode < 300)
{
    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* jsonOverview = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSString *resultStatusString = jsonOverview[@"GetMachineOverviewResult"][@"Status"];
    int resultStatus = [resultStatusString intValue];
    NSDictionary *parsedObject = jsonOverview[@"GetMachineGroupsResult"];

    NSMutableArray *groups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *results = [parsedObject valueForKey:@"MachineGroups"];
    NSLog(@"Count %lu", (unsigned long)results.count); //results.count = 7

    for (NSDictionary *parseDic in results) {
        MachineGroupList *machinegrouplist = [[MachineGroupList alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"%@", [parseDic class]);
        NSLog(@"%@", parseDic);
        for (NSString *key in parseDic) {
            if ([machinegrouplist respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)]) {
                [machinegrouplist setValue:[parseDic valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
        }

        [groups addObject:machinegrouplist];
    }
    }
    NSLog (@"GroupObjects %lu", (unsigned long)[groups count]); //groups count = 21
```

For some reason, which I cannot fathom, it parses each item three times and I end up with 21 objects instead of 7. I know it will be something simple for one of the experts here but I am new to all this and would really appreciate a helping hand here, thanks.

Edit:
Thanks a lot, here is how it now looks and it works.. The addobject was in the wrong section!

```
    for (NSDictionary *parseDic in results)
    {
        MachineGroupList *machinegrouplist = [[MachineGroupList alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"%@", [parseDic class]);
        NSLog(@"%@", parseDic);
        for (NSString *key in parseDic)
            {
            if ([machinegrouplist respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)])
                {
                    [machinegrouplist setValue:[parseDic valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
                }
                //[groups addObject:machinegrouplist];
            }
        [groups addObject:machinegrouplist];
    }
    NSLog (@"GroupObjects %lu", (unsigned long)[groups count]); //groups count = 7
```

Comment: Add a useful `description` method to your `MachineGroupList` class then log the `groups` array so you see all 21 objects. Does that give you any useful ideas?

Comment: I've logged the 21 items, it seems to be each item three times. Three attributes in each object.. I'm getting clues, but it's just not clicking for me!

Comment: I don't see it either. You only call `addObject:` once per value in `result`. Is the code you posted the REAL ACTUAL code you have?

Comment: @rmaddy He/She is actually calling `addObject:` 21 times.  The indentation in the posted code is very deceiving since the closing bracket of the `if` statement is indented as if it was the `for` loop's bracket instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is the following. First, lets comment out some of the last lines of code so that it looks like this:

```
    for (NSDictionary *parseDic in results) {
    //MachineGroupList *machinegrouplist = [[MachineGroupList alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%@", [parseDic class]);
    //NSLog(@"%@", parseDic);
    //for (NSString *key in parseDic) {
    //    if ([machinegrouplist respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)]) {
    //        [machinegrouplist setValue:[parseDic valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
    //    }

    //    [groups addObject:machinegrouplist];
    //}
}
//NSLog (@"GroupObjects %lu", (unsigned long)[groups count]); //groups count = 21
```

You'll se that you're iterating over **7** dictionaries, each of which has **3** objects.

Now, comment out the previous NSLog, uncomment the the inner for loop and add a NSLog inside that loop to see what you're iterating on.

```
    for (NSDictionary *parseDic in results) {
    //MachineGroupList *machinegrouplist = [[MachineGroupList alloc] init];
    //NSLog(@"%@", [parseDic class]);
    //NSLog(@"%@", parseDic);
      for (NSString *key in parseDic) {
    //    if ([machinegrouplist respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)]) {
    //        [machinegrouplist setValue:[parseDic valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
    //    }

    //    [groups addObject:machinegrouplist];
        NSLog(@"key: %@", key);
    }
}
//NSLog (@"GroupObjects %lu", (unsigned long)[groups count]); //groups count = 21
```

You are iterating over the 3 objects of **each** of the 7 dictionaries and since you're adding each object to **groups** outside of `if ([machinegrouplist respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)])` you end up adding **21** to **groups**

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense and I have now cleaned up the indentation to make it clearer. I am still not sure how to fix the problem, how should I be iterating through this properly to get 7 objects each with the correct 3 attributes? For some reason I cannot get my head round it!

Comment: No sooner had I posted that comment when it hit me! Thanks a lot fixed now, much appreciated!